# why document.getElementsByClassName("className") returns object

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a some dom objects that are selected with :

```
 var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("royal") ;
```

and also another objects

```
var collapsedElems =  document.getElementsByClassName("collapsed");
```

my problem occured when i tried to concat elems and collapsedElems  with array concat() method

```
 elems.concat(collapsedElems)
```

but the return type of `getElementsByClassName()` is not array actually it is
object.  I checked it at chrome console with typeof operator. that seems weird to me how can i combine this two group of object. ?

Comment: Query methods which query for multiple element return a ```NodeList``` object which stores element the same way an array does it is not an array. You need to convert it into a proper array to be able to use Array methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [HTMLcollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object which is similar to an array but not really an array so you can't call array methods using the returned value.

One hack is to use Array's prorotype methods along with [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)/[.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass the returned object as the context.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("royal") ;
var collapsedElems =  document.getElementsByClassName("collapsed");
var earray = Array.prototype.slice.call(elems, 0);
var concatenated = earray.concat.apply(earray, collapsedElems) ;
console.log(concatenated)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sjxwk0z1/)

Answer (score 5):

It returns an [HTML Collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which does things that arrays do not (such as getting live updates when the DOM changes).

If you want to get an array with elements from both collections in it, then you could:

- Create an array and then populate it by looping over each of the collections and pushing each member into it (which will give you an array) *or*
- Use `document.querySelectorAll(".royal, .collapsed");` (gets a NodeList)

Answer (score 2):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):

> **Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of
>   the given class names.** When called on the document object, the complete 
>   document is searched, including the root node. You may also call
>   getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only elements
>   which are descendants of the specified root element with the given
>   class names.

You can try this:

```
function getElementsByClassName(className) 
{
   if (document.getElementsByClassName) 
   { 
     return document.getElementsByClassName(className); 
   }
   else 
   { 
     return document.querySelectorAll('.' + className); 
   } 
 }
```