# Detect a button and then press it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling

I want to make a function that would detect a button on a web page and then click it. But I want it to click a specific item.

```js
function imready()
{
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('text-xxxs mb-02');
    for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++)
    {
        if (btn[i].innerText.indexOf('AK-47') > -1)
        {
            console.log('runtime');
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'dontrun', update: 1 }, function (response) {
        });
        btn[i].click();
        pressok();
    }
 }
```

How do I make it so that the var "btn" should equal to document.getElementsbyClassName('x') and also a different className ('y')?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question, you can use `document.querySelector('.classX.classY')` to select the needed button with both classes.
That works for the case if you only need one button on the page selected, from your code i assume exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29366682/10450049

> [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [HTMLcollection object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is similar to an array but not really an array so you can't call
> array methods using the returned value. One hack is to use Array's
> prototype methods along with .call()/.apply() to pass the returned
> object as the context.
>
> ```
> var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("royal") ;
> var collapsedElems =  document.getElementsByClassName("collapsed");
> var earray = Array.prototype.slice.call(elems, 0);
> var concatenated = earray.concat.apply(earray, collapsedElems) ;
> console.log(concatenated)
> ```
>
> Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sjxwk0z1/)