# Can't get value of numeric input if input is greater then 0

Tags: javascript, input, numeric

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Number of people*" class="user_number" min="1" max="5">
let user_number = document.getElementsByClassName("user_number");
if($(user_number).val() > 0){
            console.log($(user_number).val());
        }
```

but when i put anything more than 0 console doesn't show up help please

Comment: If you're using jQuery anyway, use `$(".user_number").val()`. And that's going to return a *string* to you, so you need to convert it to a number before comparing.

Comment: @Pointy Converting to a number is not strictly necessary in this case.

Comment: @Unmitigated well the value is always going to be a string, and the browser *should* be constraining it to a value between 1 and 5, but I'd convert it to a number anyway just out of basic defensiveness. However, you're correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366639/why-document-getelementsbyclassnameclassname-returns-object

Comment: You realize that the code will only run once? It does not keep running. You need to bind event listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an event listener for the "input" event so that the value is checked each time it changes.

```js
$('.user_number').on('input', function() {
  if (this.valueAsNumber > 0) {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" placeholder="Number of people*" class="user_number" min="1" max="5">
```